# Why doesn't the symbol address reported by `register_kprobe` (kprobes) match the symbol address in /proc/kallsyms?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, c

I want to look the address of Linux kernel symbols up using `kprobes_register` (kprobes).

After having planted kprobe for `flush_tlb_all`, I look up the address using `sudo dmesg`:

```
[1055.285848] Planted kprobe at 000000005b0a34fa
```

Conversely, `/proc/kallsyms` reports another another address for the same symbol:

```
ffffffff8ea68a80 T flush_tlb_all
```

Why do I see two different addresses for `flush_tlb_all`?

http://users.telenet.be/pynckels/2020-2-Linux-kernel-unexported-kallsyms-functions.pdf

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>

#define MAX_SYMBOL_LEN  64
static char symbol[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN] = "flush_tlb_all";
module_param_string(symbol, symbol, sizeof(symbol), 0644);

/* For each probe you need to allocate a kprobe structure */
static struct kprobe kp = {
   .symbol_name = symbol,
};

static int __init kprobe_init(void)
{
   int ret;

   ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
   if (ret < 0) {
      pr_err("register_kprobe failed, returned %d\n", ret);
      return ret;
   }
   pr_info("Planted kprobe at %p\n", kp.addr);
   return 0;
}

static void __exit kprobe_exit(void)
{
   unregister_kprobe(&kp);
   pr_info("kprobe at %p unregistered\n", kp.addr);
}

module_init(kprobe_init);
module_exit(kprobe_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your module isn’t reporting the address of the probe point, but its hash: [`%p`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html#plain-pointers) outputs a hashed address

> to prevent leaking information about the kernel memory layout

To see the actual address, use [`%pK`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html#kernel-pointers) or [`%px`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html#unmodified-addresses).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had no idea about that. `%p` will always report the address (not the hash) for user-space applications, right?

Comment: Do you know why kprobes is not able to probe the address of symbols like `sys_call_table`? In recent Linux kernels, `kallsyms` was made unexported, so it can’t be used to resolve symbol addresses anymore.

Comment: User-space applications don’t use `printk` ;-). For `printf`, POSIX [only specifies that](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) “The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printable characters, in an implementation-defined manner.”

Comment: Re. `sys_call_table`, I’ve seen your other question, I’ll answer it there.

Comment: Looking forward, I have spent a lot of time researching why kallsyms and kprobes cannot resolve e.g `sys_call_table`, but I can’t make it work, although recent articles mention kprobes as a  valid substitute for kallsyms. I don’t really have any real use case for it, except I like to understand how things work at a low-level, maybe one day being able to contribute to the Linux kernel :-)

Comment: Just to be sure, `/proc/kallsyms` contains the (live) memory addresses of kernel symbols for the current system ? Why doesn’t that exactly match the `/boot/System*` file containing addresses too?

Comment: Did you found time to look at the other question? :-)